# Why is Unity (4.6.2f1) crashing when using Leap Motion components

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am working on a Unity project using the Leap Motion.

I have upgraded Unity to the last version (4.6.2f1) and now it instantly crashes when I use the Leap Motion plugin ( Leap Motion V2 Skeletal Tracking ).

For instance, if I create an empty project and add just the HandControllerSandBox prefab from the Leap Motion plugin and start it, Unity crashes and sends me to the bug report tool, which does not help me to understand the source of the problem.
I have downloaded the last version of the Leap Motion SDK and it does not change anything.
It crashes whether the Leap Motion is plugged in or not.

Have someone ever been confronted to the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been experiencing similar problems with Unity 4.6.2, which seems to involve how Unity handles plugins. Can you revert to 4.6.1 and see if that helps? http://unity3d.com/unity/download/archive

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. Do you know if this problem will be solved soon ?

Comment: No ETA yet, but we're following up; I'll post here when I have confirmation that it's been resolved.